# Display driving directions using Google directions API

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, google-directions-api

In my app i am creating a route from source to destination and using google directions api, to display the driving directions in textbox also. I am parsing the direction response in json format and displaying the html instructions. 
The problem is suppose i am at A location and a turn is there at B location, then i am getting the html instruction related at the B location when i had reached B and not before that.

The logic that i am using to display the directions is:

```
1. Parse the json response and store the html instructions and their relevant coordinates   in a array
2. Checking the current updated location
3. Checking whether the current updated location value is present in the array, if present then displaying the html instruction corresponding to the coordinate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the issue, by calculating the distance between my current updated location and the end location, if the distance between these two coordinates is less than 100 meters then i  am displaying the html instruction for that coordinate.

You can calculate the distance between two coordinates using following piece of code:

```
CLLocation *currentLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:startLat longitude:startLong]
CLLocation *endLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:endLat longitude:endLong];
CLLocationDistance meters = [endLoc distanceFromLocation:currentLoc];
```